# Can you define a topology rule between two feature classes from different feature datasets?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology, feature-class, feature-dataset

I work in a project that I want to define topology rules between feature classes from different feature datasets, is that possible ? if no is there a solution that can do that ?

Comment: Topology is a property of a feature dataset, only available among the feature classes of that dataset. There is no workaround. The solution is to add the feature classes to a single dataset.

Comment: Or copy external features into the dataset where they are needed. I am forced into this due to standards. As long as the external feature does not change often, it is not that difficult to maintain.